# Parse error while inserting values into polygon feature

Tags: postgis, postgresql, open-source-gis

I created a polygon as follows

```
create table boundary (id int, name text);
```

table created;

```
select AddGeometryColumn ('',boundary', 'latlon' 4326,'POLYGON', 2);
```

geometry column added;

then i'm trying to insert values as follows

```
INSERT INTO boundary (id , name, latlon) VALUES ('1', 'river', GeometryFromTerxt('POLYGON(82.240 16.988,82.243 16.991,82.240 16.988)', 4326));
```

finally i got an error as follow

> <--parse error at position (position number) within geometry.

Comment: GeometryFromTerxt is spelt wrong? is that what you actually entered?

Comment: Also 3 points isn't enough to form a valid polygon, you need a minimum of 4 points.

Comment: The value of "position number" would be useful, but if your code here is a faithful representation of what you actually did, I would focus on the typo in "Terxt" :-).

Answer (score 5):

As commenters point out

- You need 4+ points to form a closed polygon
- The first and last point must be the same
- Polygons can contain multiple rings, so you need two (()) brackets around your exterior ring point list

For example, the unit square

```
POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much "Paul Ramsey" finally I created a polygon. My mistake is as you mentioned missing of two braces in POLYGON Feature.